# YA Fantasy featuring a giant blob and a warrior

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

My teacher read us "A Wrinkle In Time" when I was in the seventh grade, about 1980. At the end of this book, there was one chapter from another book, sort of a promotional sample. It featured a fantasy warrior of some kind, standing on a plain, looking at an immense giant blob, a translucent wall that contained the half-digested remains of many other warriors, their armor and their weapons, spears and such. I always wanted to read that story, never found out the name. Ring any bells?

(Since it was at the end of the L'Engle book, I thought it might be by the same publisher *Farrar, Straus and Giroux*, but I don't know how to research it).

Comment: You can find a list of books they published at http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/publisher.cgi?125

Comment: That was a good idea, good website. I believe I googled everything they published  through 1981 (except L'Engle; I didn't think it was her). None of them seemed likely. Thanks!

Comment: Do you remember what the cover of the copy of A Wrinkle in Time looked like?  That would help narrow down the edition.

Comment: No, I don't. I want to say it was the blue cover with the black and green circles, but I may be thinking of my grandmother's copy. Good question!

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161221/a-story-where-technology-is-forbidden-but-used-by-priests (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be *Beyond the Burning Lands*, the second book in the [Sword of the Spirits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_of_the_Spirits) trilogy by [John Christopher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Christopher)?

While the cover pictured here is not as explicit as you describe, your description is a close match for the protagonist's attack on a Bayemot:

> I looked over the ruins to the next rise of ground, and saw the
>   Bayemot.
>
> Except in size it was something like the bubbles of jelly that make up
>   frog spawn.  But it was almost as high as three other men, one above
>   the other, and being flattened from a true sphere by the earth's pull
>   was even greater in breadth.  It was motionless but quivered, although
>   the wind had dropped, and though it was nearly transparent there were
>   darker shapes within.

and he sees a man engulfed by it:

> I saw, or thought I saw, an arm feebly press against the jellied
>   horror which bore it down.

[image: Beyond the Burning Lands cover]

Comment: That sounds promising. Definitely worth looking into. I will check it out.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of too (just based on the question title), but it be very odd if an excerpt from this appeared in A Wrinkle in Time.  The publishers being different is the biggest thing; but it would also be quite peculiar to put an excerpt from the second (rather than first) book of a series in an unrelated volume.

Comment: Yeah, I looked to see if Christopher had ever been published by FSG, but came up empty. I haven't had the chance to check out BTBL, but the passage cited here is so compelling that it's got me wondering if I have simply misremembered the book my teacher was reading when I heard this excerpt 37 years ago! :-) Now that I recall, she also read us the first book in Christopher's Tripod trilogy, so maybe the excerpt was at the end of that instead. It would make a lot of sense.

Comment: I bought the book and read it and this is indeed the passage I remembered. Excellent! And I am enjoying the read. My teacher must have read this excerpt when she read "The White Mountains" to us, Not "A Wrinkle In Time," as I had thought. That is the only thing that makes sense. Thanks to everyone who helped me find this half-forgotten story! (P.S. -- I added the Bayemot to the Blob Monster page on TV Tropes to help others in the future). Thanks again to all!

Comment: @PeregrinePlover if you had a teacher who was reading both John Christopher and Madeleine L'Engle to you, you were pretty damn lucky.